# Min value from two arrays to create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have been refreshing my JavaScript programming skills, and I came across some interesting behaviour.

I have two arrays, and I want to create a new array that will consist of only the smallest non-zero value, from each of the two arrays' indices. For example:

```
    // input
    A = [1,3,5]
    B = [0,2,6]

    //expected
    C = [1,2,5]

    // for every index, the smallest value is chosen, as long as it is not a 0
```

I wanted to use `array.map()` to solve this problem.
This was my input:

```
    const array1 = [7,2,1,4,1,2,1,1,0];
    const array2 = [0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0,0];


    const result = array1.map(x => array2[array1.indexOf(x)] == 0? x:Math.min(x,array2[array1.indexOf(x)]));

    // expected 
    // [7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]

    // Actual output
       [7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

As you can see, the expected value at index `5` is meant to be a  `2`, but I am receiving a `1` instead.

I will really appreciate insights on what could be happening in the background.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error that you are seeing in the output is due to your use of [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). I think you are expecting `indexOf(x)` to return the index of the current element being iterated, but it actually returns the *first* index at which an equivalent value is found. This means you aren't comparing the correct values.

This is the list of indexes you are testing against in your example:

```
array1[0] to array2[0]
array1[1] to array2[1]
array1[2] to array2[2]
array1[3] to array2[3]
array1[4] to array2[2] // mismatch
array1[5] to array2[1] // mismatch
array1[6] to array2[2] // mismatch
array1[7] to array2[2] // mismatch
array1[8] to array2[8]
```

(It's really just surprising you only had one anomaly in the output).

---

If you instead use the `index` passed by `map()` your method returns the expected result in this case.

***But***, as noted by Nina in the comments, your logic is not symmetrical and will return different results if you reverse the arrays. Nina's answer provides a clean solution to this problem.

```js
const array1 = [7,2,1,4,1,2,1,1,0];
const array2 = [0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0,0];

function minByIndex(a, b) {
   return a.map((x, i) => b[i] === 0 ? x : Math.min(x,b[i]));
}

// expected 
// [7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]
console.log(...minByIndex(array1, array2));
// [7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]

// non-symmetrical output
console.log(...minByIndex(array2, array1));
// [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was really surprised by this behaviour myself! 
It had been almost a year of not programming in JS.

Thank you for taking the time to explain what is happening. I appreciate you.

Cheers!

Comment: this approach is not symetrically, because if you swap the two arrays, you get a different result, which looks like is not wanted. the main problem is the only check of of a zero of one array and not of both, which would add more complication to the callback. `7 1 1 4 1 2 1 1 0` vs `0 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 0`

Comment: Agreed @NinaScholz, I'll edit to note the problem – the logic in your answer is clean and solves the problem, but you didn't explain why the OP's code was resolving the errors that is was.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make an array of the two elements at a given index, filter out 0s, then spread into `Math.min`.

Since you want to permit zeros only in case all elements in the array are 0, I'd separate out the logic into a separate function that returns `[0]` if all elements are 0, or the array of filtered elements otherwise:

```js
const A = [1, 3, 5, 0];
const B = [0, 2, 6, 0];

const sanitize = arr => {
  const filtered = arr.filter(n => n !== 0);
  return filtered.length ? filtered : [0];
};

const result = A.map((a, i) => Math.min(
  ...sanitize([a, B[i]])
));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ah, good catch, thanks. Need some more checking to see if the filtered array is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the value and the corresponding value from the second array and get the min value of either the value or a very large value.

```js
const
    array1 = [7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    array2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    result = array1.map((v, i) => 
        (v || array2[i]) &&
        Math.min(v || Number.MAX_VALUE, array2[i] || Number.MAX_VALUE)
    );

console.log(...result);
```

A more concise approach by having a look to zero values

```js
const
    getMin = (a, b) => a === 0 && b || b === 0 && a || Math.min(a, b),
    array1 = [7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    array2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    result = array1.map((v, i) => getMin(v, array2[i]));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: I like your approach. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate `min` of two values, if value are `0` get `max` of those values.

```js
A = [1, 3, 5, 0, 0];
B = [0, 2, 6, 0, 1];

const res = A.map((a, i) => Math.min(a, B[i]) || Math.max(a, B[i]));

console.log(res)
```